# js add remove a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I see this question has been asked but I want to know how to totally remove an id from an element.

For example I have

```
<div id="page"> some content here </div>
```

I want to remove the id from the element. So after the page load the element looks like

```
<div> some content here </div>
```

This is what I have tried

```
document.getElementById("page").removeClass(" ");
```

and

```
$( "#page" ).addClass( " " );
```

The console window allows this to run but the element ID remains

Comment: First, you need to decide if it's the id you want to strip, or it is the className. The latter is done with `document.getElementById("page").className="";`

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Anyway, here is one way to do it: `$("#page").removeAttr("id")
`

Comment: wait, remove a class or remove an id?

Comment: You want to remove an `id` but you tried `.removeClass` what??? (That doesn't even make sense)

Comment: Thank you, I'm making a design for a system but I dont have access to that section of the code. So I'm having to butcher it with js. 

Thanks for the replys, this has helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first try mixes native methods with jquery methods so it should create an error (*the `removeClass` is a jQuery method, so it only applies to jQuery objects*)

On your second attempt you try to remove a class with no value..

You should use the jquery method [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and pass it the attribute name you want removed.

```
$('#page').removeAttr('class');
```

will completely remove the `class` attribute

---

If you want to remove the `id` then use

```
$('#page').removeAttr('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do that without editing the dom directly. you can emulate this with an addclass and removeclass function.

```
var addClass = function(el,class_name){
        el.className += " "+class_name;
}
var removeClass = function(el,class_name){
    el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp(class_name+"|"+class_name,"g"),"");
}
```

if you want it to be more object oriented you can do something like this:

```
function domElement(el){
    this.el = el;
    this.addClass = function(class_name){
        this.el.className += " "+class_name;
        return this;
    }
    this.removeClass = function(class_name){
        this.el.className = this.el.className.replace(new RegExp(class_name+"| "+class_name,"g"),"");
        return this;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
new domElement(document.getElementById("theElement")).addClass("class")
```

Comment: Don't edit the HTML directly using `.className`, instead use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList): `ele.classList.add(class_name)`/`.remove(...)`

Comment: [87% of users globally](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) have a browser that supports it. You can say it _is_ available in many browsers.

Comment: Well, I just got back into web development after a long hiatus so I may be out of the loop but did we get to the point where we don't have to support ie9?

Comment: IE 11 is already here and IE9 is a bit old already, some sites have already dropped support for it including [Google](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2013/11/end-of-support-for-internet-explorer-9.html) a year ago. As you can see [here](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201312-201412-bar), IE9 users have dropped to 3% worldwide, surpassed by IE8 and IE11.

Answer (score -1):

Check this example. It works for you.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmow40bL/)

```
Remove class and add new class
```